# Multiple conditions in case expression in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to order rows by string column like this:

```sql
select * from cards
order by (case gate 
          when 'mastercard' then 1
          when 'visa' then 2
          when 'fibi' then 3
          when 'uzcard' then 4
          when 'humo' then 5 
          end)
```

But I want `mastercard` and `visa` have the same index. I tried something like this:

```sql
select * from cards
order by (case gate 
          when 'mastercard' or 'visa' then 1
          when 'fibi' then 2
          when 'uzcard' then 3
          when 'humo' then 4
          end)
```

but I get this error:

```
ERROR: invalid input syntax for type boolean
```

Comment: "didn't work" is not a problem description. What did it do? Why was that wrong? Sample input and desired output would greatly help, and current output and an explanation of what's wrong with it.

Comment: Simply use `when 'mastercard' then 1` and `when 'visa' then 1` .

Comment: Case _expression_, not statement...

Comment: @jarlh my English is not that good, sorry. I will edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either create a second case with the same result, or convert your case to a full conditional.

`CASE` has two forms: the base form is

```sql
CASE 
    WHEN condition THEN result
    WHEN condition THEN result
    ...
END
```

in which case `condition` is an arbitrary boolean expression, similar to a sequence of if/else if/else if in C, or the shortcut

```sql
CASE expression
    WHEN value THEN result
    WHEN value THEN result
    ...
END
```

in which case `value` is... just a simple value, similar to a `switch` statement in C.

Here you have the second form. `'mastercard' or 'visa'` is just plain nonsense, it's not SQL at all as it will attempt to treat `'mastercard'` and `visa'` as booleans (which will fail, because neither is a valid boolean literal), then `OR` them, then will check if `gate` is equal to the result.

You can either *add a new case with the same result*

```sql
case gate 
          when 'mastercard' then 1
          when 'visa' then 1
          when 'fibi' then 2
          when 'uzcard' then 3
          when 'humo' then 4
          end
```

or expand the statement to a full conditional:

```sql
case
    when gate = 'mastercard' or gate = 'visa' then 1
    when gate = 'fibi' then 2
    ...
```

Comment: @underscore_d can you answer the question with `in` example please?

Comment: @DilsMatchanov thinking about it properly now, it wouldn't really help that much here, as Masklinn said, as it would quite a bit longer / more repetitive. But what I meant was you would write e.g. `case when gate in ('mastercard', 'visa') then 1 when gate = 'fibi' then 2`... etc. The `in` operator allows comparing the lhs against a set of multiple values.

Answer (score 1):

you can also use or operator here, this way you can prevent multiple when with same values and the list can be extended as well:

```
Case when gate in ('master_card','visa') then 1
     when gate = 'fibi' then 2
     .....
End as [column name as you want it to be]
```